# Single Element Selection & Multi Element Selection In Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m using angular js for my work. I have a list of images when i clicked any one among them, it got selected and it will shown on the result area. Here i used 2 result areas one is for single selection property and another one is for multi selection properties.

If i select any one image, It will show the corresponding image properties in the result area. Lets say image1 selected, the result area has image name & dimentions, etc

If i select more than a image, it will show those thumb images in the result area.

I have created a basic [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twkbvkzq/4/) for it

Can you help me on this. My basic code looks like below

Html

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" >
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" >    
    <ul ng-repeat="image in images">
        <li ng-click="selection($event)">{{image}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div ng-show="singleSelectedProperty">
    Single Selected Property shown here
</div>
<div ng-show="multiSelectedProperty">
    Multi Selected Properties shown here
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
li
{
    list-style: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:bold;
}
li.selected
{
    color:green;
}
```

Angular

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp",[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.images = [
    'image 1',
    'image 2',
    'image 3',
    'image 4'
    ];
    $scope.selection = function(event){
       $(event.target).toggleClass('selected'); 
    };
    $scope.singleSelectedProperty = false;
    $scope.multiSelectedProperty = false;

}]);
```

Comment: Keep an array for selected items and as per the size of that array, make decision to display the data..

Comment: how to detect selected items (whether single or multiselection)? both are different behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp",[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.images = [
    'image 1',
    'image 2',
    'image 3',
    'image 4'
    ];
    var myArr=[];
    $scope.selection = function(event,img){
    var index=myArr.indexOf(img);
        if(index==-1)
        {
            myArr.push(img);
        }else
        {
            myArr.splice(index,1);
        }
        if(myArr.length===1)
        {
            $scope.singleSelectedProperty = true;
            $scope.multiSelectedProperty = false;
        }else if(myArr.length>1)
        {
            $scope.singleSelectedProperty = false;
            $scope.multiSelectedProperty = true;
        }else
        {
            $scope.singleSelectedProperty = false;
            $scope.multiSelectedProperty = false;
        }
        console.log($scope.singleSelectedProperty);
        console.log($scope.multiSelectedProperty);
        $(event.target).toggleClass('selected'); 
    };
    $scope.singleSelectedProperty = false;
    $scope.multiSelectedProperty = false;

}]);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/twkbvkzq/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/twkbvkzq/5/ I have updated your code in the fiddle. but it doesn't work. I may miss something as i m new to angular

Comment: Just now checked, it doesn't show the blw div when i clicked on the li

 <div ng-show="singleSelectedProperty">
    Single Selected Property shown here
</div>
<div ng-show="multiSelectedProperty">
    Multi Selected Properties shown here
</div>